How create a subscription for teams chat messages?
I'm trying to create a subscription to receive notifications about user messages, but I'm receiving an ExtensionError. I'm basing myself on Team chats
I've tried to create a subscription with the sample code I've found on Microsoft but I received an error. My expectation is to create a subscription to capture all chat messages on Teams.
Permissions Granted:

My body:
{
    "changeType": "created",
    "notificationUrl": "https://teams.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/notification-listener",
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "https://teams.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/lifecycle-notification-listener",
    "resource": "/me/chats",
    "expirationDateTime": "2024-12-05T22:00:00Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientState",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}

The error I'm receiving:
Internal Server Error - 500 - 5157 ms

{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Specified method is not supported.]",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-12-02T18:44:12",
            "request-id": "7f6ebfd6-dad6-41ec-8c88-1c48478f230d",
            "client-request-id": "a3497e47-55a0-dae8-1bc6-0500c1dc4df1"
        }
    }
}




Could you edit your question and add your complete API request along with what permissions you granted?

Seems like the resource /me/chats is not correct. It should be either /users/{id}/chats/getAllMessages or /me/chats/getAllMessages

Hey @Sridevi, I've updated the post with additional information.

@user2250152 I tried with both but it didn't work :/

To make the subscription, your account must be a tenant other than 'Personal'.

Initially, I created one Partner configuration for Sri resource group by authorizing Microsoft Graph API to create resources like this:

In my case, I ran below API request in Graph Explorer to create subscription for capturing all chat messages of user on Teams:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

{
    "changeType": "created",
    "notificationUrl": "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=subId&resourcegroup=rgname&partnertopic=TeamsTopic&location=eastus",
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=subId&resourcegroup=rgname&partnertopic=TeamsTopic&location=eastus",
    "resource": "/me/chats",
    "expirationDateTime": "2024-12-02T22:00:00Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientState",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}

Response:

Make sure to grant consent to Chat.Read permission for signed-in user in Graph Explorer before running the Graph API query:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where Partner Topic created successfully as below:


Can I create a subscription only using Event Grid? I tried using lambda urls but i've same error :/

You can also use webhook URL, refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chat#example-2-subscribe-to-changes-in-user-level-chats-using-the-me-path

I'm trying to use lambdas, do i need to register the links on Azure?

Yes, try following this MS Doc and do with event grid once https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/event-grid/subscribe-to-partner-events#high-level-steps Select Microsoft Graph in Partner Authorization.

it's so strange because when i tried to create outlook subscription works fine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=javascript#throttling
"If your endpoint is unable to meet these performance characteristics, consider using Event Hubs or Event Grid as a target for receiving notifications." But i sent the response in 300ms. it's so embarrassing haha. I will try using event grid right now.

Please click on checkmark beside the answer if it works!

Of course, Thank you!!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
